# Infinite scroll advice

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

So here is my php template which I am trying to enable infinite scroll (http://wptheming.com/2012/03/infinite-scroll-to-wordpress-theme/)

```
 <?php 
 /* Template Name: Front page */ 
 get_header(); 
 ?>     
 <div class="rfp_hide" id="rhm_posts_show">
    <?php
    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('page');
    } else {
        $paged = 1;
    }       
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'posts',
        'paged'=>$paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'posts_cat' => '',
        'orderby' => 'date',            
        'order' => 'DESC'
        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    global $post, $paged; 
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    ?>  
    <div class="rhm_posts_container">
        Contents goes here
    </div>          
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>   
    <nav id="rh_nav_below">
        <ul>
            <li class="rh_nav_previous"><?php previous_posts_link( '&laquo; PREV', $loop->max_num_pages) ?></li> 
            <li class="rh_nav_next"><?php next_posts_link( 'NEXT &raquo;', $loop->max_num_pages) ?></li>
        </ul>
     </nav>
    </div>  
 </main><!--/main content -->
 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And here is my `functions.php`:

```
//Infinite scroll 
function custom_infinite_scroll_js() {
{ ?>
<script>
var infinite_scroll = {
    loading: {
        img: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/ajax-loader.gif",
        msgText: "<?php _e( 'Loading the next set of posts...', 'custom' ); ?>",
        finishedMsg: "<?php _e( 'All posts loaded.', 'custom' ); ?>"
    },
    "navSelector":"#rh_nav_below",
    "nextSelector":"#rh_nav_below .rh_nav_next a",          
    "contentSelector":"#rhm_posts_show",
    "itemSelector":".rhm_posts_container"   
 };
  jQuery( infinite_scroll.contentSelector ).infinitescroll( infinite_scroll );
 </script>
   <?php
 }
 }
  add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_infinite_scroll_js',100 );

  //add infinite scroll js
  function custom_theme_js(){
    wp_register_script( 'infinite_scroll',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js', array('jquery'),null,false );
    wp_enqueue_script('infinite_scroll');

  }
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_theme_js');
```

Could someone help why it is not working? Do I have right selectors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically what is going wrong here is that you are copy pasting without understanding the underlying code.

In the JS snippet you added to the PHP you are adding on which element the infinite scrolling should work (contentSelector)

In the example this is set to "#content", but in your code it should be ".pagination".

So if you change the contentSelector it should work :)

edit: i would advice that you change the "before" in your php to id="pagination". This might break your template, so make sure to test it with different pages, but this way you can select on the id instead of the class which is more reliable and faster

Already answered.
[infinite scroll enabling (wordpress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31956529/infinite-scroll-enabling-wordpress?rq=1)